# Is there any way to clear all list box short way?

Tags: c#, listbox

I have 15 list box inside my winForm... I am using to clear each of them like below. is there any way to clear them in short way when the application starts?

```
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        listBox3.Items.Clear();
        listBox4.Items.Clear();
        listBox5.Items.Clear();
        listBox6.Items.Clear();
        listBox7.Items.Clear();
        listBox8.Items.Clear();
        listBox9.Items.Clear();
        listBox10.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: Put them in a collection and iterate?

Comment: I would rather add them to a List<ListBox> and foreach listbox to clear them.

Answer (score 7):

```
parentControl.Controls.OfType<ListBox>().ToList().ForEach(l => l.Items.Clear());
```

Comment: What if some of the list boxes aren't top level controls?

Comment: @Servy See `parentControl`. I simply assumed all listboxes are in a control for ex a panel.

Comment: I'm saying it might not be a valid assumption to make.

Comment: @Servy Let OP decide to that.

Comment: I would rather add them to a List<ListBox> and foreach listbox to clear them. (this way you still have control on which listboxes you want to clear)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to clear all listboxes for the entire form you can use something like this:

```
foreach(var listbox in this.Traverse().OfType<ListBox>())
    listbox.Items.Clear();
```

There I use the `Traverse` helper method to get all of the children, recursively, of a particular control.  Here is its implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> Traverse(this Control root)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(root);

    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        foreach (Control children in next.Controls)
            stack.Push(children);
        yield return next;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to clear *all* listboxes, but rather only those specified list boxes, then you can try to put all of them into some container, and then traverse that container (rather than the whole form), or if that's not possible you can put them all in a collection and iterate through that collection, i.e.:

```
ListBox[] listboxes = new[]{
    listBox1,
    listBox2,
    //...
};

foreach(var listbox in listboxes)
    listbox.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: I would go for the second example, because you're still in control of which listboxes are cleared.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen It does depend on the underlying requirements.  If you *know* that any listboxes added in the future should also be cleared then such a solution adds the maintenance tasks of updating such functions.  It comes down to, semantically, do you really want to clear *all* listboxes, or just some.  For example, if there is a "clear form" button, it makes sense, semantically to actually go through, in code, and clear *all* of them.  If you don't semantically want to clear all of them, then I agree, using a collection is preferable.  That's why I included several options.

Answer (score 0):

If all the controls are in the same form(lets call this form1)

```
        foreach (Control c in form1.Controls)
        {
            if (c is ListBox)
            {
                ((ListBox)c).Clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What if some of the list boxes aren't top level controls?

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding yourself clearing them over and over in your code and you are wishing to partition the work out, make a method call to cut down on code reuse.

```
    private void ClearList()
    {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            listBox3.Items.Clear();
            listBox4.Items.Clear();
            listBox5.Items.Clear();
            listBox6.Items.Clear();
            listBox7.Items.Clear();
            listBox8.Items.Clear();
            listBox9.Items.Clear();
            listBox10.Items.Clear();
    }
```

else, put them into a collection.